# How can I change archive.php posts display?

Tags: archive-template

I would like to change `archives.php` post listing as follows.
Whenever clicked on certain link in archives select drop down box, archive page should list posts from May - Dec of that year, plus Jan - April of next year.

Eg. If i clicked on archives drop down, 2015...Archives page `http://domainname.xyz/2015/` will list all posts from the database starting from May 2015 to December 2015, also January 2016 to April 2016. This is to display posts in an annual year in the calendar.

My current wp archive have posts code like below;

```
// Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your `archives.php` is designed.

You can use built-in `wp_get_archives()` function to get posts for last 12 months:

```
<?php
wp_get_archives(
    array(
        'type' => 'monthly',
        'limit' => 12
    )
);
```

as [described](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives#Last_Twelve_Months) in the Codex.

Or you can modify the `WP_Query` using `'date_query'` parameter:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => strtotime("-1 year"), // a year before
            'before'    => strtotime("now");, // now
            'inclusive' => true, // false to exclude first and last day
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

as also [described](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) there.

Comment: Thanks for reply....I would like built-in wp_get_archives() to get the display. But for me its display start from May to dec, then jan-apr? So how can i do it? Please...I have an image to illustrate the issue... http://i.stack.imgur.com/F1yy5.jpg

Comment: my default posts archive code added above....am using twenty fifteen theme now...

Comment: I don't advise you to change `twentyfifteen` because you'll loose all changes after the next theme update. You have to develop a child theme.

Comment: ok, will make sure to build a child theme. can you help me with code?